# JPA: query for two descendants of entity by their own fields

Tags: java, inheritance, jpa

I have an abstract entity with two concrete descendants. Inheritance type is Single Table. I need to find some descendants from db. As a search criteria I use the fields which relate to the children, i.e. parent class does not have that attributes. As a result I need a list of instances of the parent entity.

Here is a pseudo-code:

```
abstract class ParentEntity {
} 

class ChildA extends ParentEntity {    
int a;    
}

class ChildB extends ParentEntity {    
String b;    
}
```

a query should be something like:

```
select ParentEntity from ChildA childA where childA.a=5 UNION select ParentEntity from ChildB childB where childB.b="hello"
```

Now my question: can I get the entities I need in ONE query, or at list with some sub-queries, or by using UNION (as far as I understand it is not supported widely in JPA)?
OR 
I have two run two separate queries anyway, unite their results and sort them manually?

JPA, Hibernate, PostgreSQL.